# Visual basic If elseIf not working

Tags: vb.net

Hello could someone please help me here. I am writing this visual basic function that for computing the price of selected items by a user. I have used an if else If loop but only the first part displays the output for example 
I am using check boxes for selection, if the first checkbox is selected and the order button clicked, the receipt is populated with the price and selected item but this does not happen for the second, third ... check Boxes. What could be wrong? Someone please help 
Here is my source code for the function

```
    Private Sub computeCurrentSelection()
    If chkugalis.Checked = True Then 'ugali fish selected
        orderAmt = lab.Text
        total = ugalif * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & total & " Kshs")
    ElseIf chkGitheri.Checked = True Then 'ugali dengu slected
        orderAmt = lab3.Text
        total = ugalid * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Ugali n dengu " & total)
    ElseIf chkUgaliB.Checked = True Then 'githeri selected
        orderAmt = lab2.Text
        total = githeri * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Githeri " & total)
    ElseIf chkPilau.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab4.Text
        total = chapo * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Pilau " & total)
    ElseIf chkPizza.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab5.Text
        total = pilau * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Pizza " & total)
    ElseIf chkMandazi.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab6.Text
        total = pizza * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "mandazi " & total)
    ElseIf chkSamosa.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab7.Text
        total = mandazi * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "Samosa " & total)
    ElseIf chkChapon.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab8.Text
        total = samosa * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "Chapati " & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water1 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml" & "Water " & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water2 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml" & "Water " & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water3 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l" & "Water " & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water4 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l" & "Water " & total)
    ElseIf chkSoda.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda1 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml" & "Soda " & total)
    ElseIf chkSoda.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda2 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml" & "Soda " & total)
    ElseIf chkSoda.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda3 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l" & "Soda " & total)
    ElseIf chkSoda.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda4 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l" & "Soda " & total)
    ElseIf chkJuice.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice1 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml" & "juice " & total)
    ElseIf chkJuice.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice2 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml" & "juice " & total)
    ElseIf chkJuice.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice3 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l" & "juice " & total)
    ElseIf chkJuice.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice4 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l" & "juice " & total)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code only first selected `CheckBox`'s logic will be executed.
Use own `If ... Then` for every `CheckBox`. In that way your code will checks every `CheckBox`.

```
Private Sub computeCurrentSelection()
    If chkugalis.Checked = True Then 'ugali fish selected
        orderAmt = lab.Text
        total = ugalif * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & total & " Kshs")
    End If

    If chkGitheri.Checked = True Then 'ugali dengu slected
        orderAmt = lab3.Text
        total = ugalid * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Ugali n dengu " & total)
    End If

    If chkUgaliB.Checked = True Then 'githeri selected
        orderAmt = lab2.Text
        total = githeri * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Githeri " & total)
    End If

    ' Other Ifs

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually that was my first option but I avoided it since I need to check also if more than one item has been selected and it did not work too. By the way would you mind telling me what is wrong with my usage of if else if?

Comment: But I have found out why they both did not work. This is actually another way of doing it as you mentioned, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check box and `ElseIf`? It's better to use Radio Buttons instead of check box if only one selection is important. Also you can remove `= True` on every if. Also keep in mind that if one `If`returns true none of the other `Else` or `ElseIf` will work.

Comment: I used check box because I wanted to enable multiple selection of items. Actually my proble is that only the if evaluates to true, the others don't even when they should(when they are checked)

Comment: Thanks people I have solved it. Actually the problem was at the point where I was calling the function, I forgot and left the previous if else statement that was placed by my partner.